# Can't access props within function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to access function that's in props after fetching data with axios but I'm getting error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I can access the same function inside jsx, but it doesn't work when I try to call it from function / axios. Here is my code:

```
function LoginModal(props) {


let emailInput = React.createRef();
let passwordInput = React.createRef();



const getToken = (props) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', {
        username: emailInput.current.value,
        password: passwordInput.current.value
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        props.closeModalHandler();
      })

}

return (
    <div className={styles.Background} onClick={props.closeModalHandler}>
    <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
        <h2>Log in.</h2>
        <div className={styles.InputContainer}>
            <input type="text" className={styles.Input} ref={emailInput} />
            <label htmlFor="" className={styles.ActiveLabel}>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.InputContainer}>
            <input type="password" className={styles.Input} ref={passwordInput}/>
            <label htmlFor="" className={styles.ActiveLabel}>Password</label>
        </div>
        <button className={styles.LoginButton}
                onClick={getToken}>Log me in</button>
        <p>Forgot password? <br/>
           Reset it <b>here</b>
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
)}
```

Comment: please add full component

Comment: If `props.closeModalHandler` is a function then you're missing the parentheses `props.closeModalHandler()`

Comment: if `props.closeModalHandler` is function .You need call this as a function `props.closeModalHandler()`

Comment: Yes please add more code - this makes it easier to understand.
Is closeModalHandler a function? If so, you miss ()

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(response)` in the promise to see if the promise is successfully getting the response

Comment: are you meaning to `return props.closeModalHandler`?

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) We need a much clearer description of the problem. That code can definitely access `props` in the only place it's using it. What makes you think it can't? (Separately: Be sure to handle errors, not just success.)

Comment: what IsmaelPadilla and @prasanth said is correct,kudos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`props` isn't passed to an `onClick` handler (the synthetic React event object is). Just remove the parameter from the `getToken` parameter list, so it closes over the one passed to `LoginModal`:

```
const getToken = () => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', {
        username: emailInput.current.value,
        password: passwordInput.current.value
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        props.closeModalHandler();
      })
      // *** Handle errors here -- you probably have to close the modal even
      // when things go wrong...
}
```